# Add a "became hot meta question" timeline event

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, per-site-meta, hot-questions, timeline

As I understand, per-site meta questions can become "hot".  For example:

> [image: Screenshot showing a math.SE example: "Hot Meta Posts: 19 What tools can be used to extract MathJax/LaTeX from scanned input?"]

However, ***this event doesn't show up on their timeline***.  For the example above, [its timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/31182/timeline) shows:

> [image: Screenshot of the timeline of the above example: "asked", "answer", "comment", and "edited" are visible.]

This is unlike non-meta questions:

> [image: Screenshot of the timeline of a non-meta example: "10 hours ago 'history' became hot network question".]

**Feature request**: Add a "became hot meta question" timeline event.

I'm not 100% sure if this is reasonable, since "hot meta questions" might have a totally different algorithm to "hot network questions".  But I thought I'd propose it to check.

Comment: Hot Meta Posts selections are based on there "hot" tab of the per-site meta, so if that can be tracked, by definition this one can too.

Comment: That's when I realize HMP have been disabled on StackOverflow only ...

Comment: The relevant post is here: [Hot Meta Posts: Allow for removal by moderators, and thoughts about future improvements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353492)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature request has been completed, per-site posts now have an event in their timeline that reads:

> became hot meta post

as shown in the screenshot for this [example post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/419163/timeline)

[image: timeline containing became hot meta post event]

However, the event is added to the timeline of posts going forward; it has not been added retroactively to posts that became *hot meta posts* before this system changed was deployed - as is the case of the example post in the question.